# Integrating a multi-calendar solution with Microsoft Exchange/Outlook

Tags: outlook, calendar, integration, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have built a platform that in essence allows users:

- to create a company profile and invite your colleagues,
- create an office with a floor plan,
- add tables and meeting rooms to the floor plan with each meeting room having a separate calendar,
- book tables and meetings in meeting rooms.

The platform is built on Python/Django.

Now I am trying to implement a sync mechanism that would work with Office 365 and local Exchange distributions. The sync would be two way, that means an event created in Outlook would trigger an event to be created in our system and vice versa.

My first attempt was to use the EWS SOAP API (with `exchangelib`). But soon I've run into problems when figuring out how to create triggers for Outlook events. This ended in failure as synchronization would involve constant bombing of slow API-calls such as iterating through accounts and checking if anything changed in their calendars.

Second attempt involved using the Microsoft Graph API that has this neat push notification feature that would solve polling (or so I thought). But as I later found out, having the administrator link his privileged Exchange account and then being able to subscribe event changes for all associated accounts in one go was not possible ([thanks to this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1200176/Consuming-outlook-streaming-notifications-in-Cshar)). So again this lead to the realization that polling (or making everyone link their personal accounts) was the only way to go.

What approach would you recommend to achieve two-way sync with Exchange that would involve only having the admin do the account linking with as little overhead and polling as possible?

Is there anyone who have developed large-scale applications that do something similar? If so, can you push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game here, but maybe what you want is the EWS `SubscribeToPushNotifications` service. It's not implemented in `exchangelib` yet, but there's a ticket for it https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/145

Implementing the basics should not be difficult.